# Browse Lists in a SharePoint App?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I created a list using first a SharePoint solution and later with a SharePoint App. The list created with the SharePoint solution appears listed in the site content however the one created with the SharePoint App doesn’t.

I understand the difference comes from the architectural differences between apps and solutions however I wonder if there is any way to browse SharePoint App items using the SharePoint out-of-the-box interface.

Comment: Do you want to show the list created in an app, in the quick launch of the Host web where the app is installed, just like you are able to see the link to app itself in it?

Comment: Yes that will be useful! But mainly I would like to have some kind of "all Site content " but for the app. As far as I know I don't get a settings icon for apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found two different approaches for this, depending on what you're trying to see. The list you created in the sharepoint app is in the app web, not the host web, so it makes sense that you can't see it in the host web contents.

To view lists, files and folders in your app structure, you can use the sharepoint REST api in the browser. This will return an xml of whatever you searched for. Here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx) to this documentation. For example, if you want to see the items in a list, your query would look like:

```
http://*appWeb*/*AppName*/_api/lists/getbytitle('*ListName*')/items
```

For site columns and content types, you can steal the query stucture from the developer site. For example, if you can see your host web's site columns using `http://devsite/_layouts/15/mngfield.aspx`, you can see your app web site columns using `http://*appWeb*/*AppName*/_layouts/15/mngfield.aspx`.

Unfortunately this doesn't work for me when trying to look at all the site's lists (I get a 403). However, you can get a native list view of a specific list using a standard url. For example, to see a list called Tutorials which is in your app web, you would browse to `http://*appWeb*/*AppName*/Lists/Tutorials`